# Gradient Fill not working in Grease Pencil in 2.83 update

Tags: grease-pencil

I just updated to 2.83 and got very confused when all the gradient fills in my Grease Pencil drawing were gone I opened my blender model, it just showed a flat fill of the primary color. I tried to recolor them but found out that no matter how much I tweaked all the settings on the gradient options I was not getting gradients between the primary and secondary color.

Is there something I am missing? I am new to Blender and started the drawing in 2.82a. When I opened 2.83 I opted for the 2.83 preference when it prompted if would like to retain 2.82 version or not.

Is it something that setting that needs to be turned on to display gradients? I tried going to Draw, Edit, Object, Sculpt modes and all showed me the same no gradient fill.

Anyone has any pointer I could try? Very frustrated and lost.

Current Setup In 2.83

[image: CURRENT SETUP IN 2.83]

Previous Result In 2.82a

[image: PREVIOUS RESULT IN 2.82A]

Trying With Another Color

[image: TRYING WITH ANOTHER COLOR]

There isn't a gradient being applied between the blue and yellow colors.

Comment: were you using an addon?

Comment: Hi susu, nope no addons. Just the regular gradient fill. I've attached an image if that helps.

Comment: Switch to Vieport Shading Mode